# Exclude link starts with a character from PREG_REPLACE

Tags: php, preg-replace, converters

This codes convert any url to clickable link:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(http[s]?:\/\/[^\s]*)/i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $str);
```

How to make it not convert when url starts with [ character? Like this:

**[http://google.com**

Comment: The `?` makes the preceding character optional, the character class around the `s` is unneeded. `[s]?` is the same as `s?`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?<!\[)(http[s]?:\/\/[^\s]*)/i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $str);
                      ^^^^^^^
```

Then, the `http...` substring that is preceded with `[` won't be matched.

You may enhance the pattern as

```
preg_replace('/(?<!\[)https?:\/\/\S*/i', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $str);
```

that is: remove the `(` and `)` (the capturing group) and replace the backreferences from `$1` with `$0` in the replacement pattern, and mind that `[^\s]` = `\S`, but shorter. Also, `[s]?` = `s?`.

Comment: but this time, if there is a <br> at the end of the url, the code grab it too... like this: http://test.com<br>

Comment: Replace `\S` with `[^\s<>]`

Comment: The last problem: when we write only "http://" our code converts it a link. I know i asked so much (sorry) but preg replace is the most difficult/complicated subject of PHP i think...

Comment: Use `[^\s<>]+`, not `[^\s<>]*`.

Comment: me again. if we want to exclude links start with "[" and "~ " what can we do? i mean double exclude patterns.

Comment: You mean to add these to `(?<!\[)`? Use `(?<![~[])`

Comment: yes but there is a space right of the ~ character, not only ~ char please.

Comment: i want to try to explain the problem. when user send a link like this no problem: [http://google.com ~ google] but when write url again it crashes like this: [http://google.com ~ http://google.com]